# How to create the IQueryable version of IEnumerable extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

Lately, I became more interested in the differences between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` interfaces, hence, I found that `IQueryable` could be very efficient in many cases over `IEnumerable`, though I'm still not having the full grasp on them. neither using the Expression trees in conjunction with `IQueryable`, but I want to increase the performance of an extension method I created:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TMember> identifier, params TMember[] values) =>
     source.Where(m => values.Contains(identifier(m)));
```

As I've understood so far, I want to do the `IQueryable` version, so, rather fetching all records from the server and filtering them in-memory, I want to fetch only the filtered records from the server, for example running this query on server: `SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3)` when calling this `books.In(x => x.Id, 1, 2, 3)`, so this what I came up with:

```
 public static IQueryable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] values) =>
    source.Where(m => values.Contains(identifier.Compile()(m)));
```

To be honest I came up with this code after some tries that spawn errors, and it works, but I'm not sure if that is how I make an `IQueryable` extension method?

**EDIT**

As the answer from xanatos has suggested, I tested it in VS and it works too,
but I have some questions to understand what is going on:

1. How do you know that it works right, what does differentiate my try from your's if they both give `IQueryable` result(off course I know mine is not correct!)?
2. Could I test it to see my self if one is correct and other not? (you mentioned you tested it with `AsQueryable`, how?)

I noticed that the result from your code is of type:

`{System.Collections.Generic.List'1[NewNS.Book].Where(x => value(System.Int32[]).Contains(x.Id))}`

where's mine is:
 `{System.Collections.Generic.List'1[NewNS.Book].Where(m => value(NewNS.Linqs+<>c__DisplayClass0_0'2[NewNS.Book,System.Int32]).values.Contains(Invoke(value(NewNS.Linqs+<>c__DisplayClass0_0'2[NewNS.Book,System.Int32]).identifier.Compile(), m)))}`

3. what do they mean, and what can I tell from these differences?

I would be so grateful if you answered these questions to help me understand how `IQueryable` work..

Comment: No. It is wrong. There is a *Compile()* so it is automatically wrong. There can't be a *Func<>* in a *IQueryable*, there can be only *Expression<>*

Comment: I can't find alternatives, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is a little complex. I've tested it with `AsQueryable()`. I haven't tested it with Entity Framework, but it should work. The code is heavily commented.

```
// The Enumerable.Contains method
private static readonly MethodInfo Contains = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains)
                                                let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                                where args.Length == 1
                                                let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                                where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                    pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                                    pars[1].ParameterType == args[0]
                                                select x).Single();

public static IQueryable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] values)
{
    // Some argument checks
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (identifier == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(identifier));
    }

    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(values));
    }

    // We only accept expressions of type x => x.Something
    // member wil be the x.Something
    var member = identifier.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (member == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(identifier));
    }

    // Enumerable.Contains<TMember>
    var contains = Contains.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TMember));

    // Enumerable.Contains<TMember>(values, x.Something)
    var call = Expression.Call(contains, Expression.Constant(values), member);

    // x => Enumerable.Contains<TMember>(values, x.Something)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(call, identifier.Parameters);

    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

The shorter version that doesn't cache the `MethodInfo` (see comments):

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] values)
{
    // Some argument checks
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (identifier == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(identifier));
    }

    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(values));
    }

    // We only accept expressions of type x => x.Something
    // member wil be the x.Something
    var member = identifier.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (member == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(identifier));
    }

    // Enumerable.Contains<TMember>(values, x.Something)
    var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new[] { typeof(TMember) }, Expression.Constant(values), member);

    // x => Enumerable.Contains<TMember>(values, x.Something)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(call, identifier.Parameters);

    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

Just for fun, the "simple" way to find the `Enumerable.Contains<T>` without using reflection (to be used with the first sample):

```
private static readonly MethodInfo Contains = ((MethodCallExpression)((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => new object[0].Contains(new object()))).Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

> 1. How do you know that it works right, what does differentiate my try from your's if they both give IQueryable result(off course I know mine is not correct!)?

Because I ran it :-) Yours can't work because there is a `.Compile()` in the middle. I know that the Entity Framework library and the LINQ-to-SQL library don't support the `.Compile()` (nor the `.Invoke()`), so I know that yours doesn't work.

> 2. Could I test it to see my self if one is correct and other not? (you mentioned you tested it with AsQueryable, how?)

There is a "smell" test, but probably even yours passes.

```
new[] { new { ID = 1 }, new { ID = 2 } }.AsQueryable().In(x => x.ID, 2, 4).ToArray()
```

The only real test is to use it against Entity Framework.

> 3. what do they mean, and what can I tell from these differences?

It is a "textual representation" of the Expression Tree. Just by looking at it, I can see the `.Invoke()` of the `.Compile()`. You must remember that with `IQueryable<>` "normally" (so excluding the `AsQueryable()` that is executed locally) your query is translated to a "language" that a "server" (often the SQL Server) can comprehend, to be executed remotely. This "translator" is very limited and knows only of some methods (the most common ones). So if you try to use anything that isn't "one of the most common methods", then your query will break on execution.

Comment: You are making it look more complicated than it is. There are two `Expression.Call` overloads (one for static and one for instance methods) receiving method name and generic type argument which greatly simplify generic (and not only) method call expressions.

Comment: @IvanStoev A) didn't know, and B) I prefer to cache the reflection when I can. C) thanks for the info.

Comment: You have created a whole new method, I thought it could be easy as calling some method. though, I'll read it carefully as you've used reflection.

Comment: re (B) you can often easily skip reflection by defining access to the method in question by an expression - `Expression<Func<....>> tmp = (..) => Enumerable.Contains(...); MethodInfo mi = ((LambdaExpression)tmp).Body;` <- that code bit is not precise, but the actual one is very close to that. Slower than caching, but less code, no linq or loops and lookups, and still much faster than reflection.

Comment: I'm sure you'd like them though :) +1

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yes, I know it... But it is still a pain. Added it to the code... It is so much ugly :-)

Comment: Yup :) but it's easy to hide it in `GetMethodInfoFromExpression<T>(expr)` utility method, and then you can just define almost all lookups with simple lambda.

Comment: @xanatos Hi, please see the question again, I've amended it

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Added some text